# Encoding of 2-bit numbers A + B

Tags: boolean-algebra, coding-theory

Consider two 2-bit binary numbers A and B ranging from integers [0,3]. Each bit in A and B have an equal probability of being either 0 0r 1.

Consider an encoding scheme for A+B (where A+B ranges from [0,6]), such that the decoder has access to any single bit in A+B. The question is: what is the encoding scheme that leaves the decoder with an equal probability of A, B being one among {0,1,2,3} by looking at any one of the bits in A+B?

Example: encoding scheme {000,001,010,011,100,101,110} leaves A with equal probability on {0,1,2,3} if we look LSB but not true for MSB.

In addition, the encoder should also satisfy the boolean addition properties. For example, if 0 is encoded as 'abc', $a,b,c \in \{0,1\}$ and 1 is encoded as 001, 0 + 1 (abc+001) should yield 001.

Any such boolean encoders or suggestions/references?

Comment: Can you clarify the required addition property? Does it not imply that 0 must be encoded as 000?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, *there can be no such encoding*, even if we neglect the "addition property".

Namely, look at every single bit in the output. We can prove that this bit must be "periodic with period $4$", i.e. it must be the same on encoding the sums $n$ and $n+4$, for $n=0,1,2$. As every bit in a multi-bit encoding must be periodic, this means that, no matter how many bits we use, we cannot possibly distinguish, say, sum $0$ from $4$, or $1$ from $5$, or $2$ from $6$.

Let $b_n\in \{0,1\}$ be a single-bit encoding of $n=0,1,2,\ldots,6$. We can see that $\frac{1}{16}(b_n+b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}+b_{n+3})$ (for $n=0,1,2,3$) is the same as the probability that $A=n$ *and* the encoding of $A+B$ is $1$. This is proportional (by a constant factor independent on $n$) to the conditional probability that $A=n$ *assuming* encoding of $A+B$ is $1$. But we want that conditional probability to stay the same, independent on $n$. Thus:

$$\frac{1}{16}(b_n+b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}+b_{n+3})=\frac{1}{16}(b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}+b_{n+3}+b_{n+4})$$

for $n=0,1,2$, which implies $b_{n+4}=b_n$.

Note that, in your example, both bits $0$ (LSB) and $1$ are periodic with period $4$ and both satisfy the desired property. The bit $2$ (MSB) is not periodic, and that is why (as per above proof) it cannot satisfy the desired property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a truth table of the addition encoding.
A, B and A+B columns represent the decimal value of addition.
The bits s2, s1, s0 represent the binary representation of the addition.

[image]

We observe that the frequency distribution of the 1s in s2, s1 and s0 and note that s1 and s0 have 50% probability of a 1 (or 0) whereas s2 is skewed with a probability of 6/16 (for 1s).

We also note that an encoding scheme is an automorphism in $GF(7)$ composed with a permutation of the resulting bits of s2, s1, s0. So, regardless of the permutation scheme used for the encoding, we need to use the non-skewed bit ie., s1 or s0 in the original unpermuted binary encoding of the sum if we want A+B to be 0, 1, 2 or 3 with equal probabilities after looking at just a single bit of the output.

Comment: "An encoding scheme is only a permutation of the bits" - can you elaborate on that? Couldn't I encode 000 as 111?

Comment: The OP mentioned that the encoding needs to preserve addition property. Coming to think of it, the encoding of the sum can be done in the finite field GF(7) since the sum is always in the set {0, 1, 2, .., 6}. We can use any encoding i.e., map of GF(7) to GF(7), so you are correct. Those are automorphisms and those would be permutation of the rows in the truth table.  This permutation of rows is not to be confused with the permutation of colums s2, s1, s0 I mentioned in my answer above which is for defining the notion of MSB/LSB. I have corrected an error in my response to use non-skewed bit.